# Selecting a number from user with multiple numbers when using the contact picker

Tags: android, android-contacts, phone-number, picker, contactscontract

I'm trying to allow a user to select a phone number from a contact using the contact picker.  However, right now all the examples I see online show how you can select a contact, but I am hoping to have a second screen then pop up if that contact has multiple phone numbers so you can specify which one you want to select (the way that text message lets you do so when you select a contact).

My question is, do you have to gather all of the numbers and then ask the user to select a number, or is this functionality already built into Android?  I'm hoping I just forgot a flag or something.

Answer (score 12):

Alternatively, you can initially display the phone numbers associated with each contact in the Contact Picker and select one that way.  Launch contact picker this way (note the different URI than my other answer):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PICK_CONTACT);
```

Then, in onActivityResult():

```
Uri result = data.getData();
Log.v(TAG, "Got a result: " + result.toString());

// get the phone number id from the Uri
String id = result.getLastPathSegment();

// query the phone numbers for the selected phone number id
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
    Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
    Phone._ID + "=?",
    new String[]{id}, null);

int phoneIdx = c.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);

if(c.getCount() == 1) { // contact has a single phone number
    // get the only phone number
    if(c.moveToFirst()) {
        phone = c.getString(phoneIdx);
        Log.v(TAG, "Got phone number: " + phone);

        loadContactInfo(phone); // do something with the phone number

    } else {
        Log.w(TAG, "No results");
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, if you add some code, you can get the display name as well:

`int nameIdx = c.getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME); //insert this below where phoneIdx is created`
and
`contactName = c.getString(nameIdx); //insert this below phone = c.getString(phoneIdx);`

Comment: @howettl is there any URI passing which would show a single dialog (within contacts application as the above URI did) to chose emails also along with phone numbers ?

Answer (score 6):

I was able to do this by creating a second dialog which shows all the phone numbers associated with a contact.
First, call this somewhere in your code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PICK_CONTACT);
```

Then in onActivityResult() use this to decide if the selected contact has multiple phone numbers, and display a dialog if so:

```
Uri result = data.getData();
Log.v(TAG, "Got a result: " + result.toString());

// get the contact id from the Uri
String id = result.getLastPathSegment();

// query for phone numbers for the selected contact id
c = getContentResolver().query(
    Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
    Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?",
    new String[]{id}, null);

int phoneIdx = c.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
int phoneType = c.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE);

if(c.getCount() > 1) { // contact has multiple phone numbers
    final CharSequence[] numbers = new CharSequence[c.getCount()];
    int i=0;
    if(c.moveToFirst()) {
        while(!c.isAfterLast()) { // for each phone number, add it to the numbers array
            String type = (String) Phone.getTypeLabel(this.getResources(), c.getInt(phoneType), ""); // insert a type string in front of the number
            String number = type + ": " + c.getString(phoneIdx);
            numbers[i++] = number;
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        // build and show a simple dialog that allows the user to select a number
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.select_contact_phone_number_and_type);
        builder.setItems(numbers, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                String number = (String) numbers[item];
                int index = number.indexOf(":");
                number = number.substring(index + 2);
                loadContactInfo(number); // do something with the selected number
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.setOwnerActivity(this);
        alert.show();

    } else Log.w(TAG, "No results");
} else if(c.getCount() == 1) {
    // contact has a single phone number, so there's no need to display a second dialog
}
```

I know this is an old question but I hope it helps.

Comment: how I can get Name as well ??

Comment: how to get the number when c.getCount() == 1. I tried contactNumber = c.getColumnIndex(phoneIdx); but it is giving me android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1 this error

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone stumbles across this again.

Another alternative to the other answers is the library https://github.com/codinguser/android_contact_picker

*Full Disclosure: I am the author of this library*

Comment: I must find a way to extend your library to pick emails, too (1 out of n)!!

Comment: I would think that should be relatively easy to do

Comment: Not so easy indeed. Anyway, I won't lose any more time with this library, since it doesn't work at all for me (I'm using Eclipse). So, I better find some other solution.

Comment: True, last I checked Eclipse support for Android library projects in Maven left much to be desired. So for Eclipse you can just download the jar from Maven central http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/codinguser/android/contactpicker/2.2.0/contactpicker-2.2.0.jar  and then include it in your project like any other library project you would use!

Answer (score 0):

it is simple explained on android developers reference:
https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/modify-data.html#InsertEdit

and simple append code:

```
String phoneNumber = "+01 123 456 789";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, phoneNumber);
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
 startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_ADD_PHONE_CONTACT);
}
```

if you needed activity result, you must listen to onActivityResult event on Activity by `REQUEST_CODE_ADD_PHONE_CONTACT` variable.