# Android contact picker - retrieving name and number

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, contacts, picker

I have researched this question a lot. I actually had this working perfectly, but now it suddenly doesn't work.

I am trying to retrive a contact's name and number using the contact picker. I want to get the name and number and use it in my app.

I used the code from the answer to this question:
[Selecting a number from user with multiple numbers when using the contact picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171328/selecting-a-number-from-user-with-multiple-numbers-when-using-the-contact-picker)

When I try to open the contact picker, I get a nullPointerException.

Here is my code:

```
@Override  
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 

        Uri result = data.getData(); //this is line 71

        // get the phone number id from the Uri
        String id = result.getLastPathSegment();

        // query the phone numbers for the selected phone number id
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, Phone._ID + "=?", new String[]{id}, null);

        int phoneIdx = c.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
        int nameIdx = c.getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);

        if(c.getCount() == 1) { // contact has a single phone number
            // get the only phone number
            if(c.moveToFirst()) {
                phoneNumber = c.getString(phoneIdx);
                contact = c.getString(nameIdx);

                //set text of view to name and number
                contactInfo.setText(contact + ": " + phoneNumber);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There are no contacts to choose from.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

logcat:

```
01-02 17:42:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(3509): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception

01-02 17:42:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(3509): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1001, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.MyActivity/com.mystuff.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 17:42:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(3509):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3329)
01-02 17:42:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(3509):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3371)
01-02 17:42:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(3509):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2700(ActivityThread.java:119)
01-02 17:42:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(3509):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1893)
01-02 17:42:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(3509):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-02 17:42:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(3509):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-02 17:42:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(3509):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
01-02 17:42:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(3509):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 17:42:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(3509):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-02 17:42:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(3509):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
01-02 17:42:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(3509):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
01-02 17:42:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(3509):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-02 17:42:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(3509): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 17:42:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(3509):     at com.emergencydialer.MainEmergencyDialerActivity.onActivityResult(MyActivity.java:71)
01-02 17:42:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(3509):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3828)
01-02 17:42:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(3509):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3325)
```

I marked line 71 in my code with a comment. This is frustrating because this code was working perfectly yesterday. Not sure what I did, and not sure why data is returning null. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should check your resultCode (RESULT_CANCELED or RESULT_OK: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#RESULT_CANCELED) and if data is null before dealing with the returned data.

You should also check wherever you throw startActivityForResult

Comment: Ok, so my resultCode is returning RESULT_CANCELED. Not sure why or how to fix it though. And I have now copied and pasted multiple answers from stackoverflow on getting contact info and all of them are returning RESULT_CANCELED.